# Статическая линковка в Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, winforms

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать статическую линковку на Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (c#)(как я понимаю, она нужна, чтобы моё приложение запускалось на любой винде)?
Копался в свойствах проекта - не нашёл.
Спасибо...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А разве в .Net используется понятие статической линковки? Вроде это актуально для C++. Сторонние dll для C# необходимо тягать с проектом. И еще, вроде есть специальные проги, которые обеспечивают слияние exe и dll, а также сборок.

Comment: Вот, к сожалению, пока и не знаю...для с++ тоже видел - для с# - нет...)
Просто сейчас пишу на Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 , а хочется, чтобы приложение запускалось на компах, где нет Framework'а...)
Можно ли это как-то реализовать?)

Comment: НЕТ! Необходимо устанавливать. В конце концов, это ведь не трудно :)

Comment: Ок...понял...)
Нетрудно - это точно...)